# Show the formula is a law of LTL

Tags: linear-temporal-logic

Show that the following formula is a law of
LTL, i. e. the formula is satisfied on all paths in all models

```
 G(p → X q) ∧ G(q → F p) ∧ p → G F p
```

I dont know how to go about that. Whats the standard procedure to go about checking the satisfiability of all  paths in all models for a given LTL formulae?

Comment: First, please put parenthesis in your formula. It seems the last "implies" should be outside the parenthesis.
Secondly, try to show that this formula holds for every path, regardless of the model.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Seems to be a modus ponens thing, roughly speaking.

Comment: Hint: rather than thinking about all possible models & paths, think about the definitions of `G`, `F`, `X`. Your proof should assume the left hand side and use these definitions to prove the right hand side, thus proving the implication *independently* of the model & path..

Comment: @cardobard_box Can you give me an example or point me to some materials regarding this?

Comment: A downvote because of ignoring the request of using paranthesis